# How to debug into AutoMapper code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map my business objects to my view model and there is a custom type I wrote that is not mapping correctly resulting in an exception.  I am trying to figure out how to setup my system so that I can debug into AutoMapper.DLL.  Does anyone know how to do this without downloading the source and building the source first?

If anyone has a link to instructions for doing this or knows how to set this up, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How have you determined that the `dll` and `pdb` are indeed from the same version?

Comment: @Oded Acutally I am pretty sure they are not the same version. I thought they would be the same since I download both off of codeplex, but it doesn't look like the PDB was updated recently.

Comment: Ah. in that case, you will need to get the source... If you don't want to compile it every time, do it once and reference the resulting `dll` and `pdb`.

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper has [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#readme) enabled and a symbols package on NuGet (the same is true for the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build). So debugging into AM works without building from source. You cannot debug into the mapping code per se, but check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Execution plan is available for AutoMapper 6.0 or newer